# System of equations that determine manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, book-recommendation

I've started reading Kazaryan's "Calculus on Manifolds", to say at start, I have some intuition on manifolds, charts and atlases, but haven't really taken any smooth manifold classes, thus started reading some booklets on given topic. But have stuck almost in the beginning. And here is why. In the book, the author gives a definition of a *k-dimensional submanifold* in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

> A **$k$-dimensional submanifold** in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a set $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. each point $x \in M$ has a nbhd $U_x \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ in which $M$ is determined by a system of equations $f_1(x) = ... = f_{n-k}(x) = 0$, where all the functions $f_i$ are smooth and the matrix of partial derivatives $(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j})$ has maximal possible rank $n - k$.

For example, consider $S^1$. Obviously, this is a manifold. Do I get the definition above correct if I say that $S^1$ is determined via equation $x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$?

Further, the author introduces the definition of *local coordinates*:

> A set of functions $y_1, ..., y_k: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a set of **local coordinates** in a nbhd of $x \in M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where M is a k-dimensional submanifold given by a system of equations $f_1 = ... = f_{n-k} = 0$, if the functions $y_1, ..., y_k, f_1 = ... = f_{n-k}$ together determine a system of local coordinates in this nbhd of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. the matrix of the 1st partial derivatives of the set $y_1, ..., y_k, f_1, ..., f_{n-k}$ is nondegenerate at $x$. In other words, the local structure of a $k$-submanifold coincides with that of $k$-space.

Reading this, there is a picture of a, say, plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e., determined by the equation $z = 0$ and local coordinates $(x,y,z) \mapsto x,\; (x,y,z) \mapsto y$. This seems to be correct and the given definitions work fine. But if consider $S^1$ again, I don't see such picture in this case. If my assumption, that $S^1$ is determined by the equation $x^2+y^2-1=0$ is correct, what are then local coordinates? I would say that, e.g. an angle between $x$-axis and radius are local coordinates in the sense that I can code any point on $S^1$ by that, but I don't really see how I can connect that with the definition of local coordinates given above.

P.S. Can someone recommend a good, but not too thick book(e.g. Lee -- Introduction to smooth manifolds) on differential geometry, that won't be too narrow, but still cover everything, that a proper math grad student should know? Thanks!

Comment: As far as book recommendations go, keep in mind that you don't need to read every part of Lee's book! IMO, that book is as readable as it gets, but I wouldn't consider it a book on differential geometry. Here is a great book for an intro to differential geometry at the graduate level: https://www.amazon.com/Differential-Geometry-Curves-Surfaces-Manifolds/dp/0821839888

Comment: @NumToez, thank you for the recommendation. By the way, what do you think about Loring W. Tu's books? He has several books on related topic(smooth manifolds, differential geometry and differential forms in algebraic topology)?

Comment: I hear that his introduction to Manifolds is very good and perhaps an easier starting point that Lee's "Smooth Manifolds". That being said, Lee's smooth manifolds is the second book in a triology, the first book is his "Introduction to Topological Manifolds". 

Tu's book "Introduction to Manifolds" is I believe the first book in a four part series? The only book of his I've tried reading is his book on Differential forms in algebraic topology. I had a hard time with it, but it's considered a classic so maybe I'm just not at that level.

Comment: Hmm, I have heard only about his "Introduction to Manifolds", "Differential Geometry" and "Forms in Algebraic Topology", what is the 4th part? I thought that Tu's book is more dense in compare to Lee's one, though they contain almost the same content (I haven't found nothing about foliations in Tu's book, but maybe I was just bad at searching).

Comment: Maybe there's only 3: Intro to manifolds, Differential forms and Differential Geometry. The latter two books are MUCH more difficult than the first in my opinion. The first book is as good a book as you can possibly ask for when first learning about Manifolds, and is highly recommended by virtually everyone. Only really smart people can understand the second two

Comment: Okay, thank you for the detailed response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your mathematical questions:

- Yes, the unit circle in the Cartesian $(x, y)$-plane may be defined by $f_{1}(x, y) = x^{2} + y^{2} - 1 = 0$. The matrix of partial derivatives, $Df_{1}(x, y) = [2x\quad 2y]$ has (maximal) rank $1$ at each point of the circle.
- Local coordinates for the circle in the sense of your second quoted passage are the independent variables if we solve the implicit equation for one variable in terms of the other. Thus, $x$ serves as a local coordinate on the set of points where $y > 0$, intuitively because we have $y = \sqrt{1 - x^{2}}$ for $-1 < x < 1$, and the portion of the unit circle where $y > 0$ is precisely the set of pairs $(x, \sqrt{1 - x^{2}})$ for which $-1 < x < 1$. Similarly, $x$ serves as a local coordinate on the set of points where $y < 0$ because $y = -\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}$ for $-1 < x < 1$. Analogously, $y$ serves as a local coordinate on the set of points where $x > 0$, or where $x < 0$.

On the other hand, $y_{1} := x$ does not serve as a local coordinate in a neighborhood of $(1, 0)$; consistent with this, the derivative matrix of the mapping $(y_{1}, f_{1})$ is degenerate (rank $1$) at $(1, 0)$. Similar remarks hold at the other three "cardinal points".

---

The definition of a manifold as a topological space locally modeled by open subsets of a Cartesian space is related, but *manifolds* as in the book you're reading are equipped in addition with an embedding into Cartesian space.

*Local coordinates*, moreover, are assumed in your book to be restrictions of Cartesian coordinates. A choice of polar angle on the circle is not a local coordinate in this sense.

You can think of an embedding as distinguishing a finite number of coordinate systems near each point of a manifold, those obtained by restricting some choice of $k$ Cartesian coordinates. There may be as many as $\binom{n}{k}$ such choices, but at points where the tangent space contains a line perpendicular to a coordinate axis (i.e., parallel to some coordinate hyperplane) there are fewer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If you don't mind, I text it the way I got it: consider circle. By the definition above, a local coordinate is a function $y_1: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the derivative matrix of $(f_1, y_1)$ is non-degenerate. Let $y_1 = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ -- local coordinates in first quadrant. Then the derivative matrix' 1st row is $[2x\;\; 2y]$(is just $Df_1$), and 2nd row is $[- \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\;\; 0]$(is $Dy_1$). So for any $(x,y) \in S^1$ the matrix is nondegenerate(the determinant is zero only in the cases when one of variables is zero).

Comment: In essence you have it, but the details are a little simpler: The two functions can be chosen to be $y_{1}(x, y) = x$ and $f_{1}(x, y) = x^{2} + y^{2} - 1$; note that both are viewed as functions on the plane. The derivative matrix is $\left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}1 & 0 \\ 2x & 2y \\ \end{array}\right]$, which has rank $2$ unless $y = 0$. (And if it matters, each Cartesian coordinate "works" on half the circle, e.g., in the first and second quadrants, or the third and fourth quadrants for $x$.)

Comment: Okay, I got it. So to say, I have several collections of charts -- atlases: 1st collection is { (i-th quadrant; $y_i(x,y) = \pm \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ or $y_i(x,y) = \pm \sqrt{1 - y^2}$ } and the 2nd one is { (upper/lower/right/left half-plane; proper projection onto $x$ or $y$) }. Did I get it right?

Comment: The usual terminology is that charts are mappings from (part of) the manifold to open subsets of a Cartesian space. For the circle, the two Cartesian coordinate projections are charts: $y_{1}(x, y) = x$ is a chart on the open top half, and is a chart on the open lower half; $y_{2}(x, y) = y$ is a chart on the open right half, and on the open left half. In each open quadrant, there are precisely two charts, namely $y_{1} = x$ and $y_{2} = y$. The square roots enter in only when we _parametrize_ (seek inverses of chart mappings).

Comment: Ah, so square roots formulas are not chart mappings, but inverse of some (seems) other chart mappings. So in my previous comment the atlas is just the latter collection, right?

Comment: Briefly yes, the four chart mappings (possibly together with restrictions to open subsets of the circle) are presumably the book's definition of an _atlas_.

Comment: Okay, thank you!